# Lombok CustomLog Example En-to-end

Tags: java, slf4j, lombok

Does anyone have a Lombok CustomLog example with a custom logger implemented in Java? All examples I see online use simple Java Util logging which I don't want to use. I would like to write a custom logger with lombok, CustomLog, slf4j.

Any pointers?